# ASP.NET A problem with Panel Direction property

Tags: asp.net

I add a user control dynamically (which only contains a table) to the Panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server"
           ScrollBars="Horizontal" Width="160" Direction="LeftToRight">

</asp:Panel>
```

when I add e.g. two user controls, they have vertical direction. Why ? I want them set from left to right (horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

The Direction property only sets whether the text is displayed left-to-right or right-to-left. It's a usability feature.

What you'll want to do is use CSS to perform what you need. Look into `float: right;`

Comment: the align is set to fight and it is the same

Comment: It sounds like the widths of the two user controls are larger than the width of the container, so one is getting pushed down below. Add containers for each of the user controls to staticly control the width of them.